# programmatically select all cells in tableview so next time they are pressed they call didDeselect

Tags: swift, uitableview, swift3, didselectrowatindexpath

I have a table view with a bunch of different sections and dynamic number of rows in each section. In the very first section I have a cell to 'select all'. Is there a quick and easy way to manually select all the cells, so the code in their `didSelect` triggers and next time the user presses one of the cells it triggers their `didDeselect`? The only way I can think of right now is to loop through all the sections, and in each section loop through `0 < indexPath.row < section's data array count` and call

```
self.tableView.selectRow(at: indexPath, animated: false, scrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.none)
self.tableView(self.tableView, didSelectRowAt: indexPath)
```

but is there a way to do it without so much looping?

Comment: isn't it better you keep track of selected state of each cell in your data source?

Comment: You should not be calling `didSelectRowAt` yourself. That's to let you know what the user did. It's pointless when you are explicitly calling `selectRow` because you already know the row has been selected.

Answer (score 3):

**No**; there is no way to do it without looping. You can make it a little easier on yourself by extending `UITableView` with a method to do it for you. This should do it:

```
extension UITableView {

    func selectAll(animated: Bool = false) {
        let totalSections = self.numberOfSections
        for section in 0 ..< totalSections {
            let totalRows = self.numberOfRows(inSection: section)
            for row in 0 ..< totalRows {
                let indexPath = IndexPath(row: row, section: section)
                // call the delegate's willSelect, select the row, then call didSelect
                self.delegate?.tableView?(self, willSelectRowAt: indexPath)
                self.selectRow(at: indexPath, animated: animated, scrollPosition: .none)
                self.delegate?.tableView?(self, didSelectRowAt: indexPath)
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Just add that to any of your Swift files at root level and then you can call `tableView.selectAll()` on any `UITableView`.

Comment: Awesome solution! , working great in Swift 5
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

NSTableView has a `selectAll` method.

Comment: This is about iOS and `UITableView`.